# store Math.PI in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

In an app I'm writing there is some logic which involves multiplying a number stored in a variable by several constant values.  I'd like to move the constant values to a JSON config file so that more can be added easily in the future without changing the code; however, one of the constants is `Math.PI`.

When an attempt is made to store the constants in a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "multipliers": {
    "a": 1000,
    "b": 2000,
    "c": Math.PI
  }
}
```

a red squiggly line appears under `Math.PI` with an error message that says "Value expected".

Is there a way to do this?

Important note: it is necessary to use `Math.PI` in the logic rather than a rounded number for pi.

Comment: JSON is a string. You cannot store `Math.PI` directly, only a string representation of it.

Comment: Math.PI isn't a valid JSON value. You'd have to store e.g. a string `"Math.PI"`

Comment: As other have said, `Math.PI` is an object. You will have to either store its value as number or store a string `"Math.PI"` and handle this in your code. Depending on the security requirements of your use case you might want to consider something like this `eval("Math.PI")`, although is generally not a good practice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use Math.PI in the logic rather than a rounded number for pi" – `Math.PI` *is* an approximation ("rounded number") of pi.

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) isn't really JavaScript object literals; only a restricted subset. You cannot use arbitrary JavaScript expressions as JSON values. Also, `Math.PI` is not the exact value of pi, it's already a rounded approximation.

Comment: Exactly, as @GuyIncognito says, it's already approximated to `3.141592653589793`, you might as well store the float number.

Comment: I’m fairly sure that using Pi with 5/7 decimal places of precision it more than accurate enough for most applications. 3.1415926535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.PI` is already an approximation - but a good enough one for almost every use

```js
console.log(Math.PI);
```

So my suggestion is to just store that in your JSON

```
{
  "multipliers": {
    "a": 1000,
    "b": 2000,
    "c": 3.141592653589793
  }
}
```